# Powerline Networking messages

Tags: networking, logging

I happened to fire up Console.app today and found lots of these messages in the log:

`13/12/2011 22:54:09.291 de.devolo.networkservice: [pktifc] write: Device not configured`

They are being generated 8 times every 5-second interval.  My network is setup as shown in the attached diagram where there are two Devolo powerline network adapters connecting the wireless access point upstairs to my modem/wifi access point/dhcp server device downstairs.  I want to know what these messages mean, whether they are a problem and if so, how to solve it.

[image: Network Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the devolo cockpit manager (you do not need it for your network to run).

If you ever need to change your devolo adapter settings, you can simply install it again, do whatever you have to do and then uninstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

On my host the launchd file /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.devolo.networkservice.plist had a syntax error. I resolved the issue by opening it as root in a text editor like

```
sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.devolo.networkservice.plist
```

replacing

```
<key>StandardErrPath</key>
```

by

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
```

(Err -> Error) and forcing launchd to reexamine the file

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.devolo.networkservice.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.devolo.networkservice.plist
```

Hope this helps you too.